# is there an option to combine two itemes in a list python?

Tags: python

i have a list of strings for example:
`list1= ['one','two','three',four','two','five']`
the outpuI i want:
`list1=['one','two-three',four','two-five']`
I want to combine every time the value 'two' appears with the next value after him

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: There certainly is no built-in way to achieve this, but you can easily to that with a for loop, maybe with a zip as well, ...

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Short answer: Yes, this is entirely possible. Please [edit] your question to show code for what you've tried based on your own research, and what went wrong with your attempts to make a [mcve] so that we can give specific answers, as this is not a code-writing or tutorial service

Answer (score 1):

You could use a comprehension over an iterator:

```
i = iter(list1)
[f"{x}-{next(i)}" if x == "two" else x for x in i]
# ['one', 'two-three', 'four', 'two-five']
```

Or, if you like it loopy:

```
res = []
for x in list1:
    if res and res[-1] == "two":
        res[-1] += "-" + x
    else:
        res.append(x)
```

Comment: This does assume there is a `next` after `'two'` in `i'`. Take the `'five'` out of the list and the code fails

Comment: Yep, until it sees different sample input with a specified desired behaviour, it does.

Comment: No I wasn't saying it was a bad answer I was only providing that end case for OP/readers.

Comment: Yeah, added a more robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is to create a new variable.
Then loop through the list and whenever you encounter  the word "Two" you merge with next word in list

```
list1= ['one','two','three','four','two','five']

temp = []
n = len(list1)
i = 0
while i < n:
    if list1[i]=="two" and i<n-1:
        temp.append(list1[i]+list1[i+1])
        i+=2
    else:
        temp.append(list1[i])
        i+=1
print(temp)
```

Result:
['one', 'twothree', 'four', 'twofive']